# How to deploy .war file to WebSphere 8.5 server?

Tags: android, tomcat, websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, war-filedeployment

I have used IBM MobileFirst platform for one of my projects. Using this, I have created an APK file(native Android) and a WAR file. The APK file calls the Webservice using HTTPURLConnection. The Worklight webservice in turn calls another externally hosted webservice on my enterprise environment.

I have tested this flow on my local machine using Emulator and Worklight Eclipse environment and my enterprise server.
Now I am trying to host the Worklight webservice on an external Webserver.

1. Can I execute this WAR file on a TOMCAT Server or will it only work with IBM Websphere?
2. If yes, I have tried to deploy to TOMCAT and it was successful. But when I try to "Start" it, it fails giving an error. The error is to be found in the Container Log files. Can someone help me as where I should look for?

Another thing, I am also trying to deploy on IBM Websphere. It has deployed successfully on version 8.5 and it is running also. Now how do I access it from Android client app?

Comment: You mention an error... what is the error... provide logs?

Comment: I think @yogesh is asking where to look for the error. From his question it seems he needs help in locating the Container Log error file.

Comment: I have created the Mobile First Platform Server 6.0 Profile using below command:create server MFPServer
But when i start MFPServer i didn't get appcenterconsole on my browser . It gave me 404 error. i have changed the port in server.xml file but got the same issue

Answer (score 0):

> have created the Mobile First Platform Server 6.0 Profile using below command:create server MFPServer But when i start MFPServer i didn't get appcenterconsole on my browser

The appcenter is not installed as part of the development environment. What you describe is the creating a dev server using the CLI tool.

> Can I execute this WAR file on a TOMCAT Server or will it only work with IBM Websphere?

Worklight supports both WebSphere Liberty and Tomcat.

> ... The error is to be found in the Container Log files. Can someone help me as where I should look for?

Find the logs folder in your Tomcat directory

> Another thing, I am also trying to deploy on IBM Websphere. It has deployed successfully on version 8.5 and it is running also. Now how do I access it from Android client app?

- Ensure that the wlclient.properties file is configured with the hostname/IP of the server
- Ensure the .wlapp and .adapter files are deployed to the same server